# LaTeX/MathJax extends out of the post box

Tags: bug, status-deferred, latex

Example: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179329/83048

As you can see, it extends out of the box the post is contained within and mildly interferes with the HNQ.

For example:

\$ThisisademonstrationofwhathappenswhenyouusetoommuchLaTeXononelineNoticehowitgoesoffoftheboxthepostiscontainedin\$

Comment: I think this issue has been here forever on all Stacks using MathJax. I wonder why the `post-layout` class doesn't have `overflow:hidden`, just in case _something_ (and not just MathJax) somehow manages to spill over the box.

Comment: [Relevant discussion on Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22539/line-breaking-in-mathjax-common-html)

Answer (score 1):

We don't have immediate plans to work on this request. We understand this a poor experience and will revisit this at a later date. We'll provide an update once we have fully investigated or completed the work.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [fix provided](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23488/427632) on the same discussion on Math.SE?